# React graphql giving error Parsing error: The type cast expression is expected to be wrapped with parenthesis

Tags: reactjs, graphql

```
  query BlogPostByPath($path: String!){
    markdownRemark(
      frontmatter : {
         path : {eq:$path}
       }
     ){
      html
      frontmatter{
        path
        title
      }
    }
  }
```

This is my code  
and error is

```
  19:19  error  Parsing error: The type cast expression is expected to
  be wrapped with parenthesis
```

> ```
> > 
> >   17 |   query BlogPostByPath($path: String!){      
> >   18 |                 markdownRemark(
> > > 19 |       frontmatter : {
> >   20 |                   ^    path : {eq:$path}
> ```

I am new with graphql. I was learning from https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VxVKMJThh04&list=PLLnpHn493BHHfoINKLELxDch3uJlSapxg&index=5 
Any help please...

Answer (score 0):

My bad as above code was

```
import React from 'react';
import Helmet from 'react-helmet';

export default function Template({data}) {
  const {markdownRemark: post} = data;
  // const post = data.markdownRemark;
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{post.frontmatter.title}</h1>
      <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: post.html}} > // error was here 
    </div>
  )
}

export const postQuery = graphql`
  query BlogPostByPath($path: String!) {
    markdownRemark(frontmatter: { path: { eq: $path} }) {
      html
      frontmatter {
        path
        title
      }
    }
  }
`
```

And the error is because div tab above is not closed.